# Webpack don't generate images

Tags: html, webpack

To be brief, here i have my webpack (below,i put the code concerned).

Actually, webpack create the image folder with an svg of the font, but not the svg images. (screenshot below)

[image]

```
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
             use: [
                'style-loader', // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                'css-loader', // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                'sass-loader', // Compiles Sass to CSS
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                 {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'image/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|otf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'font/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

and here is my HTML :

```
<div class="cc-header__left">
    <img src="image/LOGO.svg" alt="logo conseil constitutionnel" />
    <p class="cc-header__logoName"> Élection présidentielle <span>2022</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i found this solution :

```
const importAll = require =>
  require.keys().reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.replace("./", "")] = require(next);
    return acc;
  }, {});

const images = importAll(
  require.context("./image", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);
```

i've added this code to my app.js

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install `html-loader` and add new loader to config

```
module: {
  rules: [
    // ... 
    {
       test: /\.html$/i,
       use: { 
         loader: 'html-loader',
       }
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i already do this and removed it because it does not work